# Is there a way to integrate Node.JS with Objective-C/iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios, node.js

I've done my node.js middleware in JSON for a realtime application on iPhone. I wanted to know if there's any way to prepare a client for iPhone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At [i.TV](http://i.tv) we use node.js to power the API for our iPhone app. We use NSURLConnection to make the requests to the server. It's really simple. We use GET POST PUT and occasionally some other requests, express handles them really nicely. With express it's easy to send down status codes with your response so that you can confirm things went alright. NSURLConnection makes it super easy to read those status codes. For example on the server you might do something like this:

```
// let's get some users
app.get("/users", function(req, res) {
   // made up get users function
    User.getUsers(function(err, users) {
        if (err) return res.send("Users not found", 404)
        res.send({users:["sally","jane","mark"]})
    }
 })
```

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer for a good list of appropriate status codes and other information about REST.

The ExpressJS docs are pretty nice too: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: I actually wanted to get some samples for socket.io client for node.js and also is there any way to limit maximum concurrent connections to the server ?

Comment: We've played around with the objective-c socket.io client and had some good success. There are a ton of examples of server stuff with socket.io here: https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io. A specific iOS example can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCXKMVENW_o&feature=related Also see: https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa As for limiting the number of users. You can do whatever you want basically. You can use the "rooms" idea that socket.i supports and check how many people are in a room before adding a new person to it for example, but you'd have to code it yourself!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamund. the link was quite interesting :) Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the SDK can do URL requests to your node app and parse JSON. See [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the related [URL loading system docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i).